# Stop flashlight ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, flashlight

I have a flashlight app . 
I use this for making flash :

```
NSTimer * myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 
                                                     target:self 
                                                   selector:@selector(toggleFlashlight) 
                                                   userInfo:nil 
                                                    repeats:YES];`
- (void)toggleFlashlight{


    Class captureDeviceClass = NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice");
    if (captureDeviceClass != nil) {
        AVCaptureDevice *device = 
         [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if ([device hasTorch] && [device hasFlash]){

            [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
            if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchModeOff) {
                [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
                [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
                //torchIsOn = YES;
            } else {
                [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
                [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];
                // torchIsOn = NO;
            }

        [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }    
}
```

but i want to stop it when i press a button . How can i do that? It's working to stop the light it if i dont have flash.

Answer (score 0):

in you stop method (which you say works except if you have a flash), cancel any scheduled flash timer... and set the camera to torch mode

```
//stop timer
[myTimer invalidate];

//unflash
Class captureDeviceClass = NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice");
if (captureDeviceClass != nil) {
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if ([device hasTorch] && [device hasFlash]){
        [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
        [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
        [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];
    }
    [device unlockForConfiguration];
}
```